# Child Window Form does not show color scheme on gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

[image]I design a form which show color scheme on datagridview(alternate rows).it work fine. But when I call it from mdi parent form menu strip tab, Then it does not show color on datagridview(which fill on form load function).When I run only child form it shows  color on gridview3 and datagridview4.like

But when I call from parent then it does not show color in datagridview3(alternate rows) and datagridview4(alternate rows).
it look like
[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedItem = "Select Gender";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("getdata", con);
        sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Product";
        ds.Tables[1].TableName = "Category";

        dataGridView3.DataSource = ds.Tables["Product"];
        dataGridView4.DataSource = ds.Tables["Category"];


    }
    gridrowcolor();


}
public void gridrowcolor()
{
    DataGridViewCellStyle st = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    st.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView4.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
        //dataGridView4.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        //dataGridView4.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;

        int ii = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        if (ii % 2 == 0)
        {
            dataGridView4.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            dataGridView4.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle = st;
        }
        else
            dataGridView4.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Brown;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {


        dataGridView3.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
        DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        style.Font = new Font(dataGridView3.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

        int ii = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        if (ii % 2 == 0)
        {
            dataGridView3.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            dataGridView3.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle = style;
            dataGridView3.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Chocolate;
        }
        else
            dataGridView3.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
    }
}


 From Parent MDI Form

private void receiptCancelRequestToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    frm.MdiParent = this;
    frm.Show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]Assuming you have posted the code for the ChildForm, and that your application is set to MDI parent, and you have data. You should use the OnBindingComplete event of your DataGridViews calling the gridrowcolor(); from there. This should work.

```
    Form1_Load()
    {

    dataGridView4.OnBindingComplete += SetGridViewRows;
    ... // the rest of your code...

    }

SetGridViewRows(object sender, BindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{

    DataGridViewCellStyle st = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    st.Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView4.Rows.Count-1; i++)
    {
        //dataGridView4.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
        //dataGridView4.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;

        int ii = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        if (ii % 2 == 0)
        {
            dataGridView4.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            dataGridView4.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle = st;
        }
        else
            dataGridView4.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Brown;
    }


}
```

The above code - I copied in for brevity - you can actually use the same event - only using sender and the eventargs for your purpose.
using the CellFormatEvent - I do not recommend as that method might get called twice depending on what else you are doing. 
Using the BindingCompleteEvent of the DataGridView should work with out issues.

**EDIT
OK I wrote the code for you:**

```
Form1_Load()
{
    // This method subscribes to the DataGridView Binding Complete Event. Only after DdataBinding is Complete
        // For example when you do this dataGridView3.DataSource = MySource; or dataGridView3.ResetBindings(false);
       dataGridView3.DataBindingComplete += dataGridView3_DataBindingComplete;

       // This Method Subscribes to the Cell Formatting event - will be called when formatting the Cells!
    dataGridView3.CellFormatting += new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dataGridView3_CellFormatting);

// All of my other code that I have in the load event..

}

// This is called when Databinding is complete 
        private void dataGridView3_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            dgBinContent.ClearSelection();

            DataGridView myGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
            for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {


                myGrid.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
                DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
                style.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(myGrid.Font, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);

                int ii = Convert.ToInt32(myGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                if (ii % 2 == 0)
                {
                    myGrid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                    myGrid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle = style;
                    myGrid.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Chocolate;
                }
                else
        {
                    myGrid.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
        }
            }

         }

// This is called when Cell Formatting
        void dataGridView3_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].HeaderCell.Value = String.Format("{0}", e.RowIndex + 1);

            dataGridView3.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
            DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            style.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(dataGridView3.Font, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);

            int ii = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            if (ii % 2 == 0)
            {
                dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
                dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle = style;
                dataGridView3.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Chocolate;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView3.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
            }

        }
```

Comment: the given code is childform and on calling(childform.mdiparent=this).and not show color scheme on datagridview

Comment: @Farhat Ullah - I edited my response with the code - that code is set for dataGridView3 , if you need it for 4 - you can copy and paste using the same code just change the dataGridView3 to dataGridView4 in the method calls and subscriptions. You only need one of those methods, either databindingComplete or the CellFormatting. If the DatabindingComplete does not work you might just subscribe instead to BindingContextChanged of the DataGridview.

Comment: @ Farhat Ullah - your Value in the row is NULL (SQLDataAdapter in the exception declares it is the value) - it can't be converted to string - you need to verify the value is not NULL ; if you want a default value use a coalescing operator ? or ?? . Example int ii = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) ?? 0;
see this link for more info.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx